# Samba error ubuntu server 12.04.2

Tags: samba, ftp

I am attempting to install an FTP server and continue to get this error code when installing samba.

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: /usr/share/samba/setoption.pl: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide more information, such as the exact command you typed in Terminal to get that error.

First, let me include how to install Samba:

Open a Terminal Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
) and type each of these commands in:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
```

The following commands will help you install Samba via the Terminal, install dependencies for the Configuration tool, and the graphical interface.

If the error is `Permission denied`, that means you did not run the command with elevated privileges. In other words, you need to run the same command you did to get the error, only put `sudo` in front of it. It will ask you for your password to confirm. When you do that, it should allow the command to run without errors.
You should also `purge` (remove the package) with:

`sudo apt-get purge samba samba-common`

Then, rerun the commands.

Comment: I am running as root under (user) sudo su -.

Comment: What command did you use to install Samba?

Comment: apt-get install samba. tried the apt-get install samba samba-common and got the same results. the python-glade2 attempt resulted in this /var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: /usr/share/samba/setoption.pl: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@fileserver:~#

Comment: system-config-samba subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Setting up libuser1 (1:0.56.9.dfsg.1-1.2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python-central (0.6.17ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python-libuser (1:0.56.9.dfsg.1-1.2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up system-config-samba (1.2.63-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Processing triggers for python-central ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Do not use `sudo su`. Just use `sudo` when necessary. `sudo su` is just bad practice. Type `exit` to exit out of `sudo su` and then use this: `sudo apt-get purge samba4`. **After**, run the commands posted in my answer.

Comment: That seemed to have worked. I do not normally run in root i just switched because i intended to set up users and groups when I ran into this problem. thanks for the help sameetandpotatoes.

Comment: Todd, please upvote the answer if you found it helpful.